# Unity to Xcode Semantic Issue Error please assist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, core-animation

Hello guys this is my first time trying to publish an App on iOS. I am using Xcode version 13.0 beta

I am getting this Semantic Issue error while archiving and building the App on Xcode
[image].

```swift
if (@available(iOS 15.0, tvOS 15.0, *)) _displayLink.preferredFrameRateRange = CAFrameRateRangeMake(targetFPS, targetFPS, targetFPS);
```

You can check the image.

Its been days I am trying to solve this error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To properly set the `var preferredFrameRateRange: CAFrameRateRange`  property you can simply use this initializer `init(minimum: Float, maximum: Float, preferred: Float?)`. Here is a usage example:

```
_displayLink.preferredFrameRateRange = CAFrameRateRange(minimum: minFPS, maximum: maxFPS, preferred: targetFPS)
```

As the official documentation states

> If the range contains the same minimum and maximum frame rate,
> this property is identical as preferredFramesPerSecond. Otherwise, the actual
> callback rate will be dynamically adjusted to better align with other
> animation sources.

So in your case you can simply do this:

```
_displayLink.preferredFrameRateRange = CAFrameRateRange(minimum: targetFPS, maximum: targetFPS)
```